# Bug with rust compiler when building Elrond contract

Tags: multiversx

I'm in the Elrond crowdfunding tutorial and I have this error when completing the init function.

I already did

```
erdpy contract build
```

once when the contract was empty and it worked.
But when adding a body to the init function the compiler panics.

I already tried to upgrade and reinstall rust.
Also tried with 1.6 nightly version but it doesn't work.

I'm on Ubuntu-Zorin.

```
#![no_std]

elrond_wasm::imports!();

#[elrond_wasm::contract]
pub trait Crowdfunding {

    #[storage_mapper("target")]
    fn target(&self) -> SingleValueMapper<BigUint>;

    #[init]
    fn init(&self, target: BigUint) {
        self.target().set(&target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after deleting file content and retyping everything (instead of copy pasting from the tuto)